# Ubuntu 13.10 is very slow under VMware / VirtualBox running in a Windows 8.1 host

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-8.1

I am the recent owner of a new Levono Yoga 2. The specs of this are:

- 4th Generation Intel Core i7-4500U Processor (1.80GHz 1600MHz 4MB)
- Intel® HD Graphics 4400
- 8.0GB PC3-12800 DDR3L SDRAM 1600 MHz
- 512GB SSD

It's a great bit of kit. However I am having problems running VMware and/or VirtualBox.

I am trying to run Ubuntu 13.10, but the guest OS seems so so slow. Not just the GUI, which I sort of understand at very high resolutions, but the actual speed of it overall. For example, running: `rails s` which starts a Ruby on Rails web server takes around 10-15 seconds to load, while running this on my other Ubuntu laptop takes less than a second. Lots of other tasks also seem to take a long time.

These are the things I have tried:

- Switched from 1 processor to 4 and all the ones in between.
- Uninstalled local graphics driver to default to Windows driver, and tried all resolutions.
- Made sure that Unity / Gnome are using 3D acceleration and they are.
- Switched dynamic hard drive to fixed allocation and all different filesystems.
- Tried all Virtualization Types.
- Enabled / Disabled Virtualization in BIOS.
- Changed memory from 1GB to 4GB and back again.

I am using the 64-bit Ubuntu, and I have set VMware to 64-bit and 32-bit, but it is still the same. I have tried all similar options in VirtualBox too.

I am a bit stuck on this one. I cannot see any more options to change.

Comment: It's a dual core CPU clocked at 1.8GHZ, it's not exactly a powerhouse, open up the task manager and take a look at your CPU usage, I would imagine the overhead of Virtualbox combined with running Ubuntu might would taxing.

Comment: Yeah I did think this, and I tested again to confirm but with Ubuntu running, and then running the "rails s" process I reach 20% CPU Utilisation. So there is a lot of room in there! Its bugging me!

Comment: I see you are using Windows 8.1, why not try the already build-in Hyper-V. I run Ubuntu 13.10 in Hyper-V and it is fast. Also try to install some other Desktop Environment for Ubuntu like Xfce which is very resource friendly.